# Como criar uma classe e passar um valor de um atributo no construtor da classe em C#

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft

Olá, estou fazendo uma integração com a [API da Tray Comerce](http://developers.tray.com.br/) e pensei em gerar uma classe genérica com a resposta de listas. Em todas as listagens, a API implementa a seguinte classe de retorno:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("paging")]
    public ResponsePaging Paging { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sort")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Sort { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("availableFilters")]
    public List<string> AvailableFilters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("appliedFilters")]
    public List<string> AppliedFilters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(????)]
    public List<T> List { get; set; }

    public class ResponsePaging
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int maxLimit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

O problema é que para cada rota da API que faz uma listagem, o resultado dessa listagem é definido com um nome diferente (ex em `{web_api}/orders` retorna **Orders**, em `{web_api}/products` retorna **Products**, etc...)

Como eu faço para passar como parâmetro à classe qual será o nome da propriedade que será atribuída ao `[JsonProperty(????)]` da propriedade `List<T> List`?

Comment: Pesquisei e parece que você poderá substituir `DefaultContractResolver` e implemente seu próprio mecanismo para fornecer o PropertyName (em JSON). https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883987/194717

Comment: Eu fiz meu ContractResolver, só não sei como implementá-lo. Você tem algum exemplo?, eu to caçando aqui mas só acho como criar mesmo..

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver meu problema com base no que o @tony disse no comentário e também [nesse fiddle que encontrei](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAZULK). A resposta foi gerar uma `DefaultContractResolver` personalizada com esse tratamento em específico e um método de retorno que aplica essa conversão. A solução ficou assim:

```
public class Response<A>
{
    private JsonSerializerSettings settings { get; set; }

    public Response(string listName)
    {
        settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new ResponseContractResolver(listName),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
    }

    public JsonResponse<A> deserializeObject(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse<A>>(json, settings);
    }

    public class ResponseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private string ListName { get; set; }

        public ResponseContractResolver(string listName) => ListName = listName;

        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
            list.Where(x => x.UnderlyingName == "List").First().PropertyName = ListName;
            return list;
        }
    }

    public class JsonResponse<B>
    {
        [JsonProperty("paging")]
        public ResponsePaging Paging { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sort")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Sort { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("availableFilters")]
        public List<string> AvailableFilters { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("appliedFilters")]
        public List<string> AppliedFilters { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("List")]
        public List<B> List { get; set; }

        public class ResponsePaging
        {
            [JsonProperty("total")]
            public int Total { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("page")]
            public int Page { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Offset")]
            public int Offset { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Limit")]
            public int Limit { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("MaxLimit")]
            public int MaxLimit { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```

A partir dessa classe genérica, eu só preciso tratar o retorno e dizer qual é o nome que irá retornar. Assim 1 só classe "inteligente" e sem gambiarra (né não @rovann-linhalis) resolve o problema da resposta da API inteira e reduz o código drásticamente, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // resposta em string json da api (mockup de exemplo)
        string jsonResponse = "{\"fooListTest\":[{\"Id\":1},{\"Id\":2},{\"Id\":4}]}";
        List<Foo> foos = new Response<Foo>("fooListTest").DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom =] +1

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria uma herança, assim:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("paging")]
    public ResponsePaging Paging { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sort")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Sort { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("availableFilters")]
    public List<string> AvailableFilters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("appliedFilters")]
    public List<string> AppliedFilters { get; set; }

    public class ResponsePaging
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int maxLimit { get; set; }
    }
}

public class ProductsResponse : Response
{
    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<Product> List { get; set; }
}

public class OrdersResponse : Response
{
    [JsonProperty("orders")]
    public List<Order> List { get; set; }
}
```

Dessa forma, quando executar a request para Produtos, se espera um `ProductsResponse` e para pedidos, `OrdersResponse`

Comment: sim, entendo que se eu fizer uma herança eu posso resolver o problema mas se caso eu tivesse que implementar novas respostas, eu teria que a todo tempo estender a classe Response por causa de 1 referência. Isso geraria um "mundo" de classes que se resolveria com apenas 1 genérica

Comment: uma outra alternativa.... pode ser a famosa gambiarra........ rsrs

Comment: não acho que trabalhar com classes genéricas seja uma gambiarra. Principalmente porque venho de linguagens inteligentes como Python e Javascript que não dependem tanto do tipo...

Comment: não não...nao disse das classes genéricas.... falei que tem outro método da gambiarra... mas nao coloquei na resposta

Comment: a sim sempre tem rsrs